# How can I set the initial value of a Switch Button on a Gambas Qt application?

Tags: linux, qt, variables, functional-programming, gambas

I'm developing an small application written in Gambas with a Qt interface, and as an initial learning test I wanted to write a really simple control panel to start/stop a few services like `apache2`, `mysql`, `webmin` etc.

The application would look something like this:

[image]

My problem is, I have no idea how to set the initial position of the Apache button On or Off depending on the state of the service. I can extract the value from the system with `sudo service apache2 status` and some **tr/cut/grep** magic to a variable. But the interface only offers me the option of setting the value as True or False. I don't know where to place that code. The only segment I've managed to make work is the start/stop `OnClick` event, but the initial position should be set before the click. This code works only when the service status matches the button status on starting the panel.

Here's a segment of the code, if it helps:

```
Public Sub SwitchButton1_Click()
  Dim apachestatus As String
  Shell "sudo service apache2 status | grep Active | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3" To apachestatus

  If apachestatus = "active\n" Then
    SwitchButton1.Value = False
    Shell "sudo service apache2 stop"
  Else If apachestatus = "inactive\n" Then
    SwitchButton1.Value = True
    Shell "sudo service apache2 start"
  Endif

  Message.Info("apache : " & apachestatus)
End
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the status check inside `Form_Open()`:

```
Public Sub Form_Open()
    ...
    If apachestatus = "active\n" Then
      SwitchButton1.Value = False
    Else If apachestatus = "inactive\n" Then
      SwitchButton1.Value = True
    Endif
End
```